# Android 5 turn off Interruptions filtration

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Just tested my app on new Android 5.0 and found that it have some bug in switching ringer mode via Audio Manager. After set RINGER_MODE_SILENT it comes to "Allow only priority interruptions" mode and it's ok, it's how described in what's new document. But after set RINGER_MODE_NORMAL phone doesn't come back to "Always interrupt" and this is not expected behavior. User can miss the call because of it.

Does someone find solution/work around this problem? How can I turn off this filtration mode?

**Update**

Found this code in Android src. This settings is Global.ZEN_MODE. And code that should change it on set NORMAL_MODE looks like correct, but it doesn't work in Emulator and Nexus ROM. Had try to set via Settings.Global.putInt, but got error about permissions. Have no idea how to fix it =(

Made bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78158&thanks=78158&ts=1414182304

And in preview tracker https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1780&thanks=1780&ts=1414218141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found some work around. We can use **NotificationListenerService.requestInterruptionFilter** to change filtration mode. It works, but you have to add your service in "Notification access" list (it's in Sound & notification settings), otherwise you will have no permissions.